# Notepad++ - HighLight HTML tags in php

Tags: php, notepad++

Have php with echoing html tags.
notepad++ 6.4.5 is highlighting ok the tags inside php and outisde php.

notepad++ 6.5 is highlighting ok the tags only outisde php and NO HIGHLIGHT inside php code.

How to enable highlighting of tags inside php code?

**notepad++ 6.4.5**:
[image]
[image]

**notepad++ 6.5**:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I just saw this line in the change log, apparently previously this was considered a bug: 9.  Fix a tag matching bug by disabling tag matching inside PHP code blocks.

Comment: yes, thanks, I raised a bug ticket - http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/4510/ . Waiting for project owner to try to solve that.

Comment: @ihtus That would be a feature request, not a bug.

Comment: Alex: that "feature" was present in previous versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was expecting a solution from the developers of notepad++, by bringing back the feature of highlighting html code inside php code. But that is not happening...
So got a temporary workaround:

1) Open php file in notepad++

2) Set HTML languahe: go to Language => H => HTML

3) Now html tags are highlighted in php code.

If you will close and open once again the php file, you will have to execute 1-3 again.

To make this automatically done:

**EDIT langs.xml**

1) Replace

```
<Language name="html" ext="html htm shtml shtm xhtml hta"
```

with

```
<Language name="html" ext="html htm shtml shtm xhtml hta php"
```

That will make php files to be parsed as html language

2) Replace

```
<Language name="php" ext="php php3 phtml"
```

with

```
<Language name="php" ext="php1 php3 phtml"
```

That will disable php files to be parsed as php language.
If not doing step 2 => step 1 has no effect.

**EDIT functionList.xml**:

Function list will be empty after those changes.
Here is the fix: Need to edit functionList.xml

1) Replace:

```
<association langID="6" id="java"/>
<association langID="9" id="xml_node"/>
```

with

```
<association langID="6" id="java"/>
<association langID="8" id="html_function"/>
<association langID="9" id="xml_node"/>
```

2) just after last  is closed, add this (it's a copy of php_function renamed to html_function):

```
        <parser id="html_function" displayName="PHP" commentExpr="((/\*.*?\*)/|(//.*?$))">
            <classRange
                mainExpr="^[\s]*(class|abstract[\s]+class|final[\s]+class)[\t ]+[\w]+([\s]*|[\s]*(extends|implements)[\s]+[\w\\]+[\s]*)?\{"
                openSymbole = "\{"
                closeSymbole = "\}"
                displayMode="node">
                <className>
                    <nameExpr expr="(class|abstract[\s]+class|final[\s]+class)[\s]+[\w]+"/>
                    <nameExpr expr="[\s]+[\w]+\Z"/>
                    <nameExpr expr="[\w]+\Z"/>
                </className>
                <function
                    mainExpr="^[\s]*((static|public|protected|private|final)*(\s+(static|public|protected|private|final))+[\s]+)?(function[\s]+)+([\w]+([\s]+[\w]+)?([\s]+|\*[\s]+|[\s]+\*|[\s]+\*[\s]+))?([\w_]+[\s]*::)?(?!(if|while|for|switch))[\w_~]+[\s]*\([^\{]*\{">
                    <functionName>
                        <funcNameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for|switch))[\w_]+[\s]*\([^\{]*"/>
                        <!-- comment below node if want display method with parmas -->
                        <funcNameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for|switch))[\w_]+"/>
                    </functionName>
                </function>
            </classRange>
            <function
                mainExpr="^[\s]*function[\s]+\w+\("

                displayMode="$className->$functionName">
                <functionName>
                    <nameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for))[\w_]+[\s]*\("/>
                    <nameExpr expr="(?!(if|while|for))[\w_]+"/>
                </functionName>
                <className>
                    <nameExpr expr="[\w_]+(?=[\s]*::)"/>
                </className>
            </function>
        </parser>
```

**EDIT \plugins\APIs\html.xml** and **\plugins\APIs\php.xml** (this is needed for notepad++ version 6.9.1 and above)

1) Copy content in php.xml between `<AutoComplete>...</AutoComplete>` and paste it to html.xml, before `</AutoComplete>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating your PHP documents as templates of HTML documents, as seen below.  Notepad++ is just supporting good coding practices by treating your `echo` strings as PHP strings and not highlighting them.  If you want to break into HTML, then just put a `?>` to end the PHP syntax highlighting and it will highlight it as HTML. Then use `<?php` to start PHP code again, as necessary.  You don't need `echo` to output HTML, just end the `<?php ... ?>` block and type your HTML like you normally would.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
...
   <div><?php echo "content"; ?></div>
...
</html>
```

Comment: php is set as language for both cases. it's about html tags highlighting inside php.

Comment: I think that "PHP documents as templates of HTML documents" is very uncomfortable, so I will not use this.

Comment: @ihtus That is the whole point of PHP is to generate templates of HTML and other static files by processing the dynamic information on the server side.

Comment: Alex: the template you suggest is good when you have a lot of static html + some dynamic information generated by php. In most cases I work at - static html is a small part of a lot php code written for dynamic interactions. So again, the HTML template you suggest does not work for me.